# Cannot Locate Strings that Exist

Tags: android, string, android-resources

I have the following error:
[image]

From menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:appcompat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_new"
        android:title="@string/menu_item_new"
        appcompat:showAsAction="always"></item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_save"
        android:title="@string/menu_item_save"
        appcompat:showAsAction="always"></item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_delete"
        android:title="@string/menu_item_delete"
        appcompat:showAsAction="always"></item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_rate"
        android:title="@string/menu_item_rate"></item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_website"
        android:title="@string/menu_item_website"></item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_report"
        android:title="@string/menu_item_report"></item>

</menu>
```

Even though all those strings do in fact exist:

```
<string name="menu_item_new">New</string>
<string name="menu_item_save">Save</string>
<string name="menu_item_delete">Cancel</string>
<string name="menu_item_rate">Rate on Google Play</string>
<string name="menu_item_website">Website</string>
<string name="menu_item_report">Report a Bug</string>
```

I have attempted to simply re-write the code as well as clean and rebuild, yet the error persists.

How can this be resolved?

Comment: your Strings file might have some error. Check it there. 
May be you might have used some punctuation marks directly instead of unicode.

Comment: As a sanity check, please tell us where your two files live within the project.

Comment: @HarishVats It was the issue, for nearly an hour I did not see it...

Comment: @Sauron : I guess, `resource` tag is missing from `strings.xml` file. Check and let me know.

Comment: @seahawk Excellent call, that was it as well,

Comment: @Sauron : I hope your issue is resolved now. I reply the solution as answer so that the question doesn't remain under `unanswered` category.

Comment: @seahawk, yes, it was great help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`resources` tag is missing from `strings.xml` file.
Android couldn't locate the `string` resource.

Make following changes:

```
<resources>
  <string name="menu_item_new">New</string>
  <string name="menu_item_save">Save</string>
  <string name="menu_item_delete">Cancel</string>
  <string name="menu_item_rate">Rate on Google Play</string>
  <string name="menu_item_website">Website</string>
  <string name="menu_item_report">Report a Bug</string>
</resources>
```